# Cloudera Date Functions

Tags: hive, cloudera, impala, bigdata

I am trying to use Cloudera Impala Date functions on Amazon Elastic Map Reduce.
[The documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) states that there is a function called `dayname`, but when I execute this query:

```
SELECT dayname(ts) FROM  `default`.`data_impala_local` LIMIT 100
```

I am getting

> (150) Unsupported scalar function: DAYNAME.

This goes with many functions not just this one. Any one knows what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your data?

Comment: I found out the function  is not supported on  Impala  1.2 , if you can perform upgrade to version 2  .

Answer (score 0):

Probably your date is not converted properly.

I assume `ts` corresponds to unix timestamp thus according to documentation you should first convert it to the string. I suggest to try something like:

```
SELECT dayname(from_unixtime(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
FROM  `default`.`data_impala_local` LIMIT 100;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found out the function is not supported on Impala 1.2  , the documentation is for 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out that Amazon  uses  Impala   1.2   and the documentation is for  Impala 2.0   .  So its important to check the version of the documentation .

Functions like DayName and DayofWeek  and many others are not supported on Amazon until today  .